# Is this normal?

Tags: php, class, static, late-static-binding

I don't get how this late static binding works.

```
abstract class A{

  final public static function doprint(){
    print get_called_class() . '<br>';
  }


  public static function wrapper(){
    self::doprint();
    static::doprint();
  }

}

class A2 extends A{}    

A2::wrapper();
```

get_called_class() prints A2 in both cases, even when I called the doprint method with self. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get_called_class()** always returns the class you actually call. You call **A2::** so it's A2.

On my site there's a tutorial with an **LSB singleton abstract class**. I'm not linking here because there's always a zombie vigilante that comes and removes the links without even looking. *But it's in my description.*

The catch with LSB is that a method in A can call a method in B which can call a method in A back. **See this example:**

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // Pretty text output
// LSB Parent
class A {
    // NOLSB: Will call Current Class method
    static public function TriggerSelf() {
        self::OverrideMe();
    }
    // LSB: Will call Inheriting Class method (or Current if none Inherits)
    static public function TriggerStatic() {
        static::OverrideMe();
    }
    // Method to Override
    static public function OverrideMe() {
        echo 'A here', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// LSB Child
class B extends A {
    // Override by LSB
    static public function OverrideMe() {
        echo 'B here', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

A::TriggerSelf(); // <- NO LSB
A::TriggerStatic(); // <- LSB (but not inheritance)

B::TriggerSelf(); // <- NO LSB
B::TriggerStatic(); // <- LSB (with inheritance, so it works)
```

See how **B::TriggerStatic()** allows A to call a B method while **B::TriggerSelf()** calls a A method. **That's LSB.** Parent class static methods can call child class static methods. It's pretty much static abstracts :)

*Study the example, it'll make sense.*

Answer (score 1):

I think `get_called_class()` is telling you which class was called, and its output is correct.

Late static binding allows the `self` context to bubble up, so methods defined higher can operate on the called method's object.